# Как сделать шанс выпадения определённой переменной?

Tags: python, случайные-числа

как сделать так, чтобы например число 1 выводилось с шансом 80%, а число 2 с шансом 20%?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26196078/8324991

Comment: Если выбор из двух вариантов, то можно без choices: `print(1 if random.random() < 0.8 else 2)`

Answer (score 4):

**Вариант 1:** - для Python 3.6+ используем функцию [random.choices()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) из встроенного модуля `random`:

```
from random import choices

res = choices([1,2], weights=[.8, .2])
```

**Вариант 2:** - используем функцию [np.random.choice()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) из модуля Numpy:

```
import numpy as np

res = np.random.choice([1,2], p=[.8, .2])
```

---

сравнение производительности:

```
In [48]: N = 1000

In [49]: %timeit choices([1,2], weights=[.8, .2], k=N)
183 µs ± 661 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [50]: %timeit np.random.choice([1,2], size=N, p=[.8, .2])
41.3 µs ± 1.07 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [51]: N = 10000

In [52]: %timeit choices([1,2], weights=[.8, .2], k=N)
1.8 ms ± 38.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [53]: %timeit np.random.choice([1,2], size=N, p=[.8, .2])
203 µs ± 7.42 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [54]: 183 / 41.3
Out[54]: 4.430992736077482

In [55]: 1.8 * 1000 / 203
Out[55]: 8.866995073891626
```

Comment: Я посмотрел время выполнения в Colab. Оно везде минимально: (1) - 0,013 секунд, (2) - 0,008 секунд, поэтому разницы почти нет, но можно учесть то, что вариант 1 возвращает список, состоящий из выбранного числа, а вариант 2 - само число.

Comment: @vlados155, `np.random.choice([1,2], size=N, p=[.8, .2])` - вернет вектор из N элементов. Также при желании можно указать кортеж, тогда вернется матрица указанной размерности

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение.

Comment: @vlados155, также добавил сравнение производительности для 1.000 и 10.000 элементов